# Cannot get my Batch file to accept user input and set a prompted variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, uac, psexec

I have read several posts about this and have spent about an hour on this, changing a lot of things, and made a lot of progress.

I created a batch file that uses PSEXEC so I can apply group policy updates and do various client maintenance in the network

This file worked fine until I started adding if statements to make it easier for users to select which domain they want to use.

I cannot seem to get the if statement to capture the input and then set the variable.

My output of PSEXEC is that the username  / password is incorrect after attempting to connect to the remote computer or server. It starts the PSEXEC service, then connects, then it is says `PsExec could not start cmd on computer123` and `The user name or password is incorrect.`

Here is the script:

```
    @echo off &setlocal
    :: BatchGotAdmin
    :-------------------------------------
    REM  --> Check for permissions
    >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

    REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
    if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
        echo Requesting administrative privileges...
        goto UACPrompt
    ) else ( goto gotAdmin )

    :UACPrompt
        echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        set params = %*:"=""
        echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

        "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        exit /B

    :gotAdmin
        pushd "%CD%"
        CD /D "%~dp0"
    :--------------------------------------
    cls
    :start
    :::
    :::           *** Log into a remote computer to execute a command ***
    :::
    :::                (psexec DEVICE -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD cmd)
    :::
    :::                  PSTOOLS must be installed in the %path%
    :::

    :::
    for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do @echo(%%A

    set /p computerName="Enter computer/server name: "
    echo "Enter the domain of your admin username:"
    echo =========================
    echo Enter '1' for domain1
    echo Enter '2' for domain2
    echo Enter '3' for domain3
    echo =========================

    set /p domainName=
    if %domainName% == 1 (
      set domainName = "domain1"
      goto continue
    )
    if %domainName% == 2 (
      set domainName = "domain2"
      goto continue
    )
    if %domainName% == 3 (
      set domainName = "domain3"
      goto continue
    ) else (
      goto choice
    )

    :continue
    set /p userName="Enter your Admin username: "
    powershell -Command $pword = read-host "Enter password " -AsSecureString ; $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword) ; [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR) > .tmp.txt & set /p password=<.tmp.txt & del .tmp.txt
    psexec \\%computerName% -u %domainName%\%userName% -p %password% cmd
    :choice
    set choice=
    set /p choice="Do you want to restart this file? Press 'y' for Yes or 'n' for No then Press ENTER: "
    if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
    if '%choice%'=='y' goto start
```

The `username or password incorrect error` seems to mean that the PSEXEC command does not have the right variable string for `domainName`

If I but `""` around the `1`,`2`,or `3`, the file quits after entering the input.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are critical in a string `set` statement.

```
  set domainName = "domain1"
```

will set *domainname<kbd>Space</kbd>* to *<kbd>Space</kbd>"domain1"*

remove the spaces. A more reliable `set` is

```
  set "domainName=domain1"
```

to set *domainname* to *domain1*

`choice` is a batch keyword and a poor er, choice, for a label or variable-name.

Comment: thank you for your input. I removed the spaces as above and PSEXEC connects to the computer, then fails after trying to launch `cmd`. I am not sure why this is occurring. I also changed `continue` and `choice` to `nextstep` and `resetfile`. I even tried changing the `"%domainName%"` in the `if` statement to `"!domainName!"` but that made no difference.

Comment: After doing a lot of testing, I now am prompted for a password again after it tries to connect to the computer. When I enter the same password as before, it fails to `run PASSWORD on COMPUTER`, so any ideas there?

Comment: I know it's not the psexec command because i ran it outside of the batch file and it runs fine.

Comment: did you remove the spaces in `set params = %*:"=""`? Since you're using `%params%`, this would be replaced by *nothing* using your posted batch. I'd suggest `echo`ing the `psexec` command temporarily to ensure the correct or expected same-as-manual data is being transmitted.

Comment: I have a special character at the end of my password. I echo-ed the command, and it is not picking that up.

Comment: What do you mean by ` %*:"=""?`

Comment: I did remove the spaces so they are `set "domainName=domain1"` in the if statements

Comment: I added 'set params = %*:"=""?' to the file and it made no difference

Comment: The problem with `set var =...` is that the space is included in the variable `set`, regardless of where it is. Hence in the 13th line of your posted code, `set params = %*:"=""` should be `set params=%*:"=""` (actually that won't work) to set the variable `params`. In the floowing line, you use `%params%` which will be replaced by *nothing*. You need to first set `params` to `%*` and *then* set `params` to whatever you're trying to set it to - you can't use `%*:?=` directly. You need to explain quite what you are attempting to do with the `set params=` statement. currently it's a mystery.